# Assess the power of the GPU using Vulkan

Tags: gpu, vulkan

Vulkan has a lot of properties of Physical Device. Is it possible to get some information to assess GPU performance? How I know there are size of max workgroup and max number of invocations. Are there some properties of hardware performance like: number of cores, frequency, max data rate and so on? Maybe somebody had an experience to assess GPU performance using Vulkan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some kind of GPU information through [VkPhisicalDeviceProperties](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceProperties.html) and [VkPhisicalDeviceFeatures](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures.html).
You can get performance counters through the extension [VK_KHR_performance_query](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_performance_query.html).
There may be obscure, vendor-specific extensions that can tell more GPU details like the ARM extension [VK_ARM_shader_core_properties](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_ARM_shader_core_properties.html).
But information such as GPU load, operating frequency and others you usually get through the operating system or a specific library provided by the GPU vendor.